# Only show comments with lengths less than, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a function that randomly pulls in 3 comments from my database. the only problem is sometimes I have a comment with 150 words and the 2 next to it have a sentence or around 50 words.

Would it be possible to only show comments with a maximum of 70 words?

```
  function getIndexComments(){
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comments ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<li><span>".$row['company']."</span>".
        "\"".$row['comments']."\"" .
        "</li>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: maximum seventy words, or trim longer comments to 70 words?

Comment: Question, just to make sure, you want 70 words or characters max? Words might be trickier to calculate...

Answer (score 3):

This solution will truncate comments longer than 70 words and add a `...` after the truncation.

```
SELECT company, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(comments, ' ', 70), '...') AS comments
FROM tbl_comments
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

However, if you actually want to ***filter out*** comments that have > 70 words from the result-set, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_comments
WHERE ((LENGTH(comments) - LENGTH(REPLACE(comments, ' ', ''))) + 1) <= 70
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

^ What this essentially does is count the number of spaces in the `comments` field and adds 1 to that count => giving us word count... then we check if that count is over 70, and if so, filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to use REGEXP '.{0, 70}' or something like that :)

Comment: No, that is an answer to his question. Not just a comment.

Comment: You refer to an answer that might not even be there anymore. The order in which answers are displayed changes, that makes this answer obsolete.

Comment: You guys are polluting the answers, mind if I report you for usless chatter on comments? BTW This solution is viable and probably better than the aforementioned ones. Do not, for your petty semantics loving, downvote solutions that can help others...

Answer (score 0):

If you define a word as a string separated by a whitespace, something similar to this would work:

`SELECT x FROM y WHERE SUM( LENGTH(x) - LENGTH(REPLACE(x, ' ', ''))+1) < 70`

You could expand it by adding commas, periods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can leave CSS to handle the rendering using

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

this will add dots and with a fixed width/height of the container you can render as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to eliminate comments just because they are too long? I suggest you do an output that limits the comments length in display. Meaning, add `...` to the comment if it's too long.

Put them all in divs and add this to it style:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 200px;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below is to truncate comments to length of 70 characters without chopping the words.

```
SELECT
  LEFT(str, cutpos) AS str1
FROM (
  SELECT
    comments AS str,
    70 - IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(comments , 70))), 0) - 1, 0) AS cutpos
   FROM tbl_comments
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could truncate this with PHPs [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Something like this should do it, I think (untested):

```
function getIndexComments(){
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_comments ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $comments = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($row['comments'], 0, 70) . '...';

        echo '<li><span>' . $row['company'] . '</span>"' . $comments . '"</li>';
    }   
}
```

This will truncate the $row['comments'] to 70 words and append a '...'.